# Mysql: update same data in row

Tags: mysql

How can I change the same data in a row?
Lik the gender, there are "Female" and "Male"
What can I go If I want to change "Female" to "F" and "Male" to "M"

Thank you so much!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a CASE expression:

```
update tablename
set 
  gender = case gender 
    when 'Male' then 'M' 
    when 'Female' then 'F'
  end,
  gender_st = case gender_st 
    when 'Male' then 'M' 
    when 'Female' then 'F'
  end;
```

Or simpler, keep the 1st char of the gender:

```
update tablename
set gender = left(gender, 1),
    gender_st = left(gender_st, 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a rather straight-forward operation.

I think your question should be;
"How to update all data in a column, which meets a condition".

```
UPDATE <TABLE_NAME>
SET gender = 'F'
WHERE gender = 'Female';
```